# Chromium Edge-based WebView2 (object not set as a instenece of an object)

Tags: windows, browser, webview, visual-studio-2019, microsoft-edge

i am wanting to make a fast web browser and something that works and someone told me about Microsofts new Microsoft Edge Browser control WEbView, so I downloaded The NuGet And it come up with this error "Object not set as a reference of an object" and "Onject not set as an instence of an object" do i need to add a line of code that gives the object value or something can someone please help.

im using Visual studio 2019. and .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: Could you please provide [a minimal code to reproduce the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? How do you use WebView2? We can't locate the issue with only your description. Beside, you could refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32) to see how to use WebView2.

Comment: I didn't use any code I just put the browse in my project and i went to run it and it just comes up I can tell you the location tho. the location is in the Form1 Designer.cs

Comment: It seems that your app is a Windows Forms app. Have you followed [the steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/winforms) to use WebView2 in Windows Forms apps? Please note that you should have [Microsoft Edge (Chromium) Canary channel](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/download/) installed on Windows 10, Windows 8.1, or Windows 7.

Comment: Yeah i followed them, it told me to download the plug-in pre-release and then look in the visual studio toolbox and drag it into my project and then change the source to Microsoft.com and I did that and then he told me to debug the program and when I did it came up with this error

Answer (score 0):

I tested WebView2 in winform according to the doc and it can work well. Please note that you need Edge Canary to get it work. If you use other versions, it might throw the error you came up with.

The test result is like below. Test against Win 10 version 1903, OS build 18362.900, Edge Canary 85.0.562.0 :

[image]

Comment: I'm confused, whats Edge Canary And Where do I get it, I have the newest Microsoft edge installed on my computer I'm running windows 10 2004

Comment: You could download Edge Canary Channel in this link: https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download

Comment: ok I got it working but now I have another problem when i navigate do a website it just comes up with the website url i typed in the browser not the website, how can i fix this

Comment: the code i typed into my search button is 'WebView21.NavigateToString(TextBox1.Text);'